# Putting a cap on the display of an integer in python?

Tags: python, integer, pygame

I am making a pygame game and I want it to recharge the cannon (its a ship warfare game) fire recharge number.

I have the recharge set to 1.75 seconds (1750 in pygame time) and I figured out 5.714285714285714 is the number you must multiply 1750 by to get 10,000. By getting 10,000 I want to cap it so it only says the first 2 numbers. Like instead of saying:

148833 it will say 14.

Code for the variable change:

```
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - starttime >= 1750:
    count = "Fire!"
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - starttime < 1750:
    count = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - starttime) * 5.714285714285714
```

If there isn't a way to cap an integer, I'll keep divided by 1000 to make it a smaller number.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'says the first 2 numbers'?  You mean 'print out the first two digits of the number'?  Or 'set a variable to contain the first two digits of the number'?

Comment: You should use `else:` to replace your second `if`.

Comment: Also, what is it that you are trying to 'cap'?  `pygame.time.get_ticks() - starttime)`?  And when you say 'cap', do you mean that you will always show only the first 2 digits, or you will show the actual number if the number was < 10000, and only show the first 2 digits if the number was >= 10000?

Comment: @iForests fixed the "else" and "if"... and my questioned was answered Zehnpaard, but I meant first two digits printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [str()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) returns a string from integer, and first two digits is [0:2]. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

```
>>> count = 148833
>>> print(str(count)[0:2])
14
```